# delete a file present in multiple directories based on the status of find command in unix

Tags: bash, file, find

I need to delete a file present in multiple directories if it is found else ignore. I tried the following snippet.

```
   ls $dir/"$input.xml" 2> /dev/null
        var = `echo$?`
        if [[ $var == 0 ]]; then
            echo -e "\n Deleting...\n"
            rm $dir/"$input.xml"
```

It failed.

Can anyone suggest me a better solution or modify the above snippet to suit the solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say to delete if found, else ignore. Then in your comments you say you must throw an error if not found. Please explain **clearly** what you want.

Comment: You are using `ls` command in example and asking for `find` command in question statement. Please explain properly in details atleast in question

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what do you mean with "*delete a file present in multiple directories if it is found else ignore*". Assuming that you simply want to delete some files that are somewhere under $dir, do this:

Use *find* to find the files, and pipe to *xargs rm*:

```
find "$dir" -type f -name "*.xml" | xargs rm
```

If your filename is likely to contain spaces then do this:

```
find "$dir" -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

To supress the *rm* error message in case there are no files:

```
find "$dir" -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 rm 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: i need to delete a file if its found. If its not found i need to throw error message. This file is found in many directories

Answer (score 0):

To make your code working Try this [Insert space],

```
`echo $?`
```

Instead of this,

```
`echo$?`
```